# How to fix `Argument of type number is not assignable to string`?

Tags: angular, typescript

New to angular 2 & typescript.  Trying to test some pipes.  I keep getting this error in my tests:

> ERROR in [default]
>   .../inflection.pipe.spec.ts:22:47
>   Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'string[]'.

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

```
//pipe.ts

import { .... }

    @Pipe({name: 'inflection'})
    export class InflectionPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: string, args: string[]): any {
        console.log(args);
        return inflection.inflect(value, args)

  }
}

//spec.ts
import {....}

describe('InflectionPipe', () => {
    // provide our implementations or mocks to the dependency injector
    beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [
            InflectionPipe
        ]
    }));

    it('should inflect different values', inject([InflectionPipe], (inflectionPipe: InflectionPipe) => {

        expect(inflectionPipe.transform('goose', 2)).toEqual('geese');

    }));


});
```

Comment: it sould be `declarations: [
            InflectionPipe
        ]` not `providers:[InflectionPipe]` I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at your `transform` signature

```
transform(value: string, args: string[])
```

and look how you are trying to call it

```
inflectionPipe.transform('goose', 2)
```

It expects a `string[]` but you are passing a number. Not sure what you are trying to do, but you should fix it accordingly. Maybe `transform('goose', ['2'])`